# Unable to find version 'x.x.x' of package 'PushSharp'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, pushsharp

While executing command:

> PM> Install-Package PushSharp -Version 2.2.1

I am getting this error:

> Install-Package : Unable to find version '2.2.1' of package 'PushSharp'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package PushSharp -Version 2.2.1
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

My environment is Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

**NOTE:** I need **Version 2.2.1** because my project is old and certain libraries are missing in new PushSharp version 4.x (Which is my currently installed PushSharp library) like `PushBroker`.

```
Dim push As PushBroker = New PushBroker() //This is giving error
```

> Type "PushBroker" is not defined.

All references are added. Here are my imports.

```
Imports PushSharp
Imports PushSharp.Google
Imports PushSharp.Apple
Imports Newtonsoft
Imports PushSharp.Core
```

Thanks

Comment: I could install it in VS 2015 -  could it be that you need a higher .NET version?

Answer (score 0):

I could install it in VS 2015 -  could it be that you need a higher .NET version? 
Otherwise try it first with an empty solution and compare your solution packages.config against the empty packages.config. Maybe there is some conflict.

Comment: I have tried to install on VS2015 and it is giving me different error: `PushSharp 2.2.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0`. And by the way where I can find `packages.config` file?

Comment: I used a simple console application for my test.

Comment: Mine was WebAPI project

Answer (score 0):

In Push Sharp version 4.x , you use PushBroker as  a ApnsBroker.
please reefer following link:
https://libraries.io/nuget/PushSharp/4.0.10